# Generating Power Set Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This is the algorithm to print PowerSet From a Set

```
Input: Set[], set_size

1. Get the size of power set
   powet_set_size = pow(2, set_size)

2  Loop for counter from 0 to pow_set_size
     (a) Loop for i = 0 to set_size

          (i) If ith bit in counter is set
              Print ith element from set for this subset
     (b) Print seperator for subsets i.e., newline
```

Can anyone explain me what it means by If the 
ith bit in counter is set.

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you know about binary?

Comment: Binary is a number representation in base 2 ..

Comment: A digit in binary is called a bit. Bits are numbered right to left, so if the i'th bit is set, that means that the i'th digit (right-to-left) is equal to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number is in a computer represented in binary notation. For instance 5 is represented as:

```
00000000101
```

Because the zero'th bit is one and so is the second. Thus `2^0+2^2=5`.

You can for instance test whether the `i`-th bit is "set" (meaning it is equal to one), using the following test:

```
(n&(1<<i)) != 0
```

1. You first shift 1 `i` places to the left. Such that it creates a number where only the `i`-th bit is set.
2. Next you perform a bitwise and such that the result differs from zero if and only if that bit is set for `n` as well.
3. Finally you perform that check.

If you count in binary, eventually all possible combinations of zero's and one's will be enumerated:

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```